# How to maintain different SW versions with different package names

Tags: java, package

We are providing software for an embedded JavaME device. Besides standard JavaME APIs, this device provides some proprietary API's which were in packages like `com.somecompany.icm.io` for example.

Because of legal issues, the packages were renamed in later firmware revisions to `com.othercompany.io` e.g. but with the same class names, interfaces and functionality.

Now, what I could do is running `sed` or similar over our code base and rename every required package and then commit it to our VCS as "the new" version. Unfortunately, we need to provide updates for both firmware revisions so bug fixes or even features then needs to be merged back into the old version.

I was thinking about having a special ANT build task that first copies all sources to another directory, runs the `sed` script and then compiles it again. This is not very elegant but may work (haven't done this yet).

I know this might be a very special case, but maybe someone can come up with a smarter solution.

**[UPDATE]**

I've been thinking about this for a while and came up with the following idea: I wrote a small application that contains the following line:

```
try {
    System.out.println("[somecompany] File 'foo' exists: " + com.somecompany.icm.io.File.exists("foo"));
} catch(NoClassDefFoundError ex) {
    System.out.println("[othercompany] File 'foo' exists: " + com.othercompany.io.File.exists("foo"));
}
```

I've compiled this providing both the libraries of somecompany and othercompany as classpath. `File.exists` is just some arbitrary static method to test this idea.
And it actually does work on both target devices:

Old firmware:

```
[somecompany] File 'foo' exists: false
```

New firmware:

```
[othercompany] File 'foo' exists: false
```

However, this does only work for static methods and class initialization. However, this won't work on class instances and instance method access.

Now, one thing that could be done is writing two versions of a factory classes for each firmware version. Then, I could use the code above to determine at runtime which firmware is running and load the right factory class.

```
MyFactory factory;
try {
    com.somecompany.icm.io.File.exists("foo");
    factory = new SomeCompanyFactory();
} catch(NoClassDefFoundError ex) {
    factory = new OtherCompanyFactory();
}
// use the factory to create instances of classes of the right package
```

Obviously, the instances have to be wrapped in classes that implement a common interface which is applicable in my case.

This would result in a bit of class overhead (in terms of number of classes and jar file size) but since these classes won't be loaded there should be no effect (or only a little) on the memory usage (We have very limited RAM on this target).